# Closed form for infinite sum over unit balls in odd dimensions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I stumbled upon the infinite sum
$$
1 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2\pi)^k}{(2k + 1)!!}
= 2 + \frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{(2\pi)^2}{3\cdot 5} + \frac{(2\pi)^3}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 7} + \dots
$$
(This is actually the sum of the volume of the unit balls in *all* odd dimensions.)

From computation, it seems that it converges to something around 12.43. I'm wondering if there's a closed form. Any hints?

(The sum of the volumes of the unit balls in all *even* dimensions is known to be $\exp(\pi)\approx 23.14$. The sum is the same as above, just with even factors in the denominator.)

Comment: Take a look at the answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482211/double-factorial-series

Comment: According to Mathematica, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^k}{(2k+1)!_2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{e^x\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$$
But I am unable to produce a proof.

Comment: One of the proofs is here -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275413/standard-way-to-evaluate-sum-k-0-infty-fracxkk1-2/4275491#4275491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks for the comments to @K.defaoite and @Svyatoslav.*

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4275491/36678), we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k + 1/2)!} 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^k (2k)!!}{(2k + 1)!}
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\exp(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \erf{\sqrt{x}},
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2\pi)^k}{(2k + 1)!!} = 
\frac{1}{2} \exp(\pi) \erf(\sqrt{\pi})
$$
which indeed is $12.429316728301792$...

This means that the sum of the volumes of the unit balls in all dimensions is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |S_n|
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty |S_{2n}| + \sum_{n=0}^\infty |S_{2n + 1}|\\
&= \exp(\pi) + \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \exp(\pi) \erf(\sqrt{\pi})\right)\\
&= 1 + \exp(\pi) \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \erf(\sqrt{\pi})\right)\\
&\approx 35.57
\end{align}
$$